# Can't access 2nd Wordpress instance in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've installed a second instance of wordpress in a subdirectory but when I try to access mysite.com/newsite I get a 404 error page on the root wordpress install page/theme. I've looked at the .htaccess files which have rewrite rules, tried adding an exception for the /newsite folder in the root .htaccess but it had no effect.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this set of instructions](http://liquidbook.com/2014/08/installing-second-wordpress-instance-subfolder/)? According to that site, the .htaccess in the second installation should look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /newsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Try that out if you haven't and let me know if it works.